# takePersistableUriPermission via ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT fails on a custom documents provider but only for API < 26

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, storage-access-framework

I have a custom DocumentsProvider implementation that works flawlessly for a user to choose photos or videos for use by the app, as long as the Android API is 26 or greater. Using APIs 21-25 I get a security error similar to what is described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331956/trying-to-takepersistableuripermission-fails-for-custom-documentsprovider-via). However I am already doing everything mentioned in that post as a solution.

Manifest entry:

```
    <provider
        android:name=".storageproviders.FacebookProvider"
        android:authorities="${facebookDocumentsAuthority}"
        android:exported="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </provider>
```

My Intent setup looks like this:

```
    Context context = InTouch.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
    Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
```

The launcher that references this intent looks like this:

```
    mLaunchFileChooserIntent = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if ( result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        Intent initialIntent = result.getData();
                        if ( initialIntent != null) {
                            // This may have one or more files
                            ArrayList<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<>();
                            Uri uri = initialIntent.getData();
                            if (uri != null) {
                                // Single file chosen
                                uriList.add(uri);
                            } else {
                            *
                            *
                            *
                            }
                            // I then call my utility method handleMediaClipData() passing the following as the argument for 'takeFlags':
                            // (initialIntent.getFlags() & URI_PERMISSIONS_FLAGS)
```

Use of that launcher is done as the response to a button press, like this:

```
    mFiles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            closeFABMenu();                   
            mLaunchFileChooserIntent.launch(contentSelectionIntent);
        }
    });
```

I have validated that using an emulator running API 21 that the intent that comes back from the SAF chooser (`initialIntent` above) has its flags set to 0x43, which is correct - 0x40 is the `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION` which was given by my provider via the manifest entry at the top of this post, and 3 is the combo of values `(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)`.

Yet when I try to use the `takePersistableUriPermission()` API using the associated Uri returned by that intent along with the flags argument from above for the 'takeFlags' argument `(initialIntent.getFlags() & URI_PERMISSIONS_FLAGS)` like this:

```
public static Disposable handleMediaClipData(final MediaCreate mediaCreate,
                                             final ArrayList<Uri> mediaUris,
                                             final int takeFlags,
                                             final String listId,
                                             final AppCompatActivity activity) {
    Context context = InTouch.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
    final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    *
    *
    *
    resolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
    *
    *
    *
```

I get the following security error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10084
```

The exact same code flow (app ui, custom DocumentsProvider) on both an emulator and physical device using API 26 or greater WORKS.

If I try my app using API 21 using SAF and choosing something from the phone outside of the app specific area (and thus not incorporating my custom DocumentsProvider), it ALSO WORKS.

Therefore, I assume it is something I am not doing in the custom DocumentsProvider for devices running API 21-25 but I have no idea what that might be.

What is different for implementing a custom DocumentsProvider that might affect the ability to take persistable permissions for APIs 21 to 25 vs. 26 and higher?

I assume from the error there is some sort of reconciliation going on under the covers to match a Uri that is returned from the chooser with the Intent that originally launched the chooser, but I don't understand how that relationship works, where to start looking to debug it, or if I'm even on the right track with that assumption.

Comment: Much too much code. Where should we look.? And which statement produces that error? `URI_PERMISSIONS_FLAGS` Why your own macro? Just use the flags we all know. And one you added again. Much to complicated code. Why do you need two uri array lists to show us your problem? Please post minimal code.

Comment: But in general: you should only try to take permissions which are offered to you.

Comment: I use my own constant (not a macro) because I use those same two permissions everywhere and it is actually simpler than spelling them out every time.

Comment: It makes no sense to set these flags in an intent for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. They do nothing. You better remove them to get cleaner code.

Comment: You only repeat your code. Why? We saw it already. Take those flags out and see that they have no effect.

Comment: OK - I think I just added those in recently as a test to see if they would make any difference. I didn't have them in the code originally. Still the same problem. I was talking about the flags needed for the takePersistableUriPermission() API call.

Comment: For that one I'm actually just using the two flags READ and WRITE. Still fails prior to 26. So I think this is a problem with provider somehow, not the code I posted.

Comment: Due to your complicated code where i have no idea what you are doing i repeat: take only flags which are offered to you.

Comment: btw at your suggestion I simplified the post. Take another look.

Comment: Offered in onActivityResult. The place where you can take them. Do away with handleMediaClipData function and take permanent permission in onAcyivityResult. Bother us with simple code please.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you understand how this works. See this post, answered by CommonsWare. It is *exactly* what I am doing and what IS WORKING in API 26 and greater, and IS NOT working below that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990189/content-provider-grant-uri-permission. And btw, that is essentially where I am taking them, I'm just using the newer 'registerForActivityResult' approach since onActivityResult() is now deprecated for Fragments.

Comment: All signs point to a problem that for some reason, the custom DocumentsProvider I wrote which works fine in API 26 and above is somehow not satisfying some reconciliation check made by the takePersistableUriPermission() API used in APIs 21-25 between the Uri produced by the provider, and the intent originally created and handed to the SAF.

Comment: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {                intent.setType("*/*");                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uri);            } else {                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/*");            }

Comment: @thecr0w - thanks for responding but I don't understand how you think your suggestion will help. At the time I am creating the intent to use with the SAF chooser, there is no 'uri' yet. That's the point of using SAF, to return one or more Uris that represent what the user chose. When I get the Intent back in the ActivityResultLauncher callback there is no point in altering the intent, all I can do is utilize the resulting Uri(s) that point to the items the user chose, and try to take permission on them. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with your implementation of `DocumentsProvider`, it's the expected behavior on API 19-25 when working with SAF.

Even if you get a `SecurityException` while trying to take persistable URI permission you'd still always have access to URIs exposed from your own `DocumentsProvider`.

Thus it'd be a good idea to catch and ignore the `SecurityException` specially from your own URIs.

> Note: If your app contains a DocumentsProvider and also persists URIs returned from ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, or ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT, be aware that you won’t be able to persist access to your own URIs via takePersistableUriPermission() — despite it failing with a SecurityException, you’ll always have access to URIs from your own app. You can add the boolean EXTRA_EXCLUDE_SELF to your Intents if you want to hide your own DocumentsProvider(s) on API 23+ devices for any of these actions.

Here's a note from official Android Developers blog that confirms this behavior - https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/building-a-documentsprovider-f7f2fb38e86a

Comment: I've previously read aspects of that blog a dozen times while creating my DocumentsProvider classes and didn't properly connect the dots on what "your own URIs" in that paragraph actually meant until now :)  So I've modified my code to test for my "authority root" in the URI to catch when my DocumentsProvider classes are in play and not attempt to take the permission. Works perfectly. Thanks!